# How can i convert a complex matrix in python into a scientific notation for latex

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am a bit desperate. The matrix `eigen_vectors` is a bit too big for latex and that's why I need to convert it into a scientific note with for example 3 digits. Additionally, the imaginary part which is zero should be listed as 0i. How can I convert a complex matrix in Python into a scientific notation for latex? `A_q1a` is a 6x6 complex matrix. I tried many ways of converting. Sometimes the imaginary part is removed and sometimes nothing happens.

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
from print_latex import print_latex as pl
from latexifier import latexify

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('system_q1a.mat')
np.array(mat)
A_q1a=mat["A_q1a"]
[eigen_values,eigen_vectors]=np.linalg.eig(A_q1a)
imag_eigen_values=np.imag(eigen_values)
real_eigen_values=np.real(eigen_values)
f_imag_eigen_values=imag_eigen_values/(2*np.pi)
damping_eigen_values=-real_eigen_values/(np.sqrt(np.power(real_eigen_values,2) + np.power(imag_eigen_values,2)))


#Convert to Latex
#pl(eigen_values,'bmatrix')
pl(eigen_vectors,'bmatrix')
#pl(imag_eigen_values,'bmatrix')
#pl(real_eigen_values,'bmatrix')
#pl(f_imag_eigen_values,'bmatrix')
#pl(damping_eigen_values,'bmatrix')


def print_latex(matrix,arraytype):
    
    print(latexify(matrix,arraytype=arraytype,fmt="%.1e"))
    
    
    return
```

Due to a file request, I add a link to GitHub where you can find the Matlab file.

Edit: https://github.com/romanv22/Roman.git

Comment: `mat = scipy.io.loadmat('system_q1a.mat')` could you please provide the file so other people can test the code and help you easier?

Comment: @Caridorc Done :) The question is edited.